# Google API client library

Tags: php, api, authentication

I have recently downloaded the Google API client library for PHP, uploaded it to my website, and used the code provided by Google to connect with my calendar. The first part works very well. I get sent to: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http` where I push the accept button. I get redirected back to this file with the authcode. But this line fails:
    $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);

```
require_once ('google-api-php-client/autoload.php'); // path to autoload.php
if ($_GET[code] == FALSE) {
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('My client ID');
$client->setClientSecret('My secret');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://'); // path to this file.
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
header("location: $authUrl"); // sends me to account.google.com  I accept and get send back to    this file :-)
}
Else {
//$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));
$authCode = $_GET[code]; // get authcode from google
//Exchange authorization code for access token
$accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode); //Fatal error: Call to a member function on a              strong text**non-object in authenticate() on line 23
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
```

Comment: How does it fail? Does it give an error message? We need more information to help you.

Comment: should that be $_GET['code']

Answer (score 0):

the `$client` variable needs to be in scope outside of the `if` branch, as in:

```
require_once ('google-api-php-client/autoload.php'); // path to autoload.php

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('My client ID');
$client->setClientSecret('My secret');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://'); // path to this file.
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

if ($_GET['code'] == FALSE) {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header("location: $authUrl"); // sends me to account.google.com  I accept and get send back to    this file :-)
} else {
  //$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));
  $authCode = $_GET['code']; // get authcode from google
  //Exchange authorization code for access token
  $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode); //Fatal error: Call to a member function on a              strong text**non-object in authenticate() on line 23
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
}
```